# Creating an object from instances of the classes it (multiply) inherits from

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Say I have a class C that inherits from I, S1 and S2. Let's say that I is just an interface and S1 and S2 are simple structs with no functions. None of the classes/structs share any common members or methods and don't inherit anything else.

It's guaranteed there will be no problems with diamond hierarchies and the like. The purpose of the structs is just to provide an alternative to composition.

The code would look something like this:

```
class C : public I, public S1, public S2
{
  ...
};
```

Now, the useful aspect of this is that I can simply cast an instance of C to an S1 or S2 whenever I need an object that is just that part of it. The point being that using an existing C as an S1 or S2 (or even an I) is straightforward (and useful).

However, on top of that use case I would also like to be able to create a new instance of C when provided with an object of S1 and an object of S2. The first (and only) thing that came to mind was a constructor that would work something like this:

```
C::C(const S1& s1, const S2&s2) : I(), S1(s1), S2(s2)
{
  ...
}
```

However, there are three issues I have with that solution:

- It requires additional code and additional constructors from my
  class C which is pretty inelegant and I assume there's gotta be a
  better way.
- It requires that my structs S1 and S2 provide copy constructors (or move constructors if implemented differently). While that works fine for me, even with the default constructor, it's a clear indicator that this is not a general solution and is thus bad or at the very least incomplete.
- Due to the design of the framework and and the application I'm making in it, this solution would require even more functions and code than just in the barebones example. Once again, it's not much of an issue to write the code, but it's simply more code to maintain and think about. On top of that, using simple composition with instances of S1 and S2 inside of C would end up being comparably, if not even less verbose.

So, to sum up:

What are the possible ways to create an object that multiply inherits from some classes when we already have finished objects of those classes (or just the necessary stuff to make them, even)?

Of those ways which is the most general, simplest and least likely to lead to headaches and complications, be they logical or syntactical?

Comment: You can implement implicit [user defined conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) if you want to keep using composition and still want your type to be implicitly castable to it's component types.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not the reason I decided to ditch composition. It was the syntactic overhead of having instances of S1 and S2 in my classes. S1 and S2 being very primitive building blocks in the design (and being needed in multiple places), I grew very annoyed very quickly with constantly having to write something.x just to get to the x I use in basically 80% of the member functions.

Additionally, the "x"s are also used in many loop conditions and I dislike having such a (relatively) complex and long expression in them.

I'd prefer my loops just < x instead of < something.x etc.

Comment: Can you describe how you imagine creating a `C` would look like in an ideal world? It's not clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did before (and basically am still doing). But for the reasons I stated in the previous comment, I decided to experiment with multiple inheritance today and just ran into this hurdle.

Comment: Hm, that's a good question that I've been to trying to figure out myself. 

Ideally, it would be great if I could have some incompletely built C and then just do c = s1; c = s2; and only the s1 and s2 parts of c would change with each assignment. 

The syntax is a bit illogical, but basically something like that, where I could only assign to a parent's part of the class. Virtually the opposite of what happens with casting a C to an S1 or S2.

Could I maybe even do something like static_cast<S1>(C) = someS1; with the expected result?

Comment: Can `C` even be both `S1` and `S2` at once, and are they? Your proposal says "yes", your comments say "not really".

Comment: You can provide assignment operators to `C`, one that take an `S1` and one that takes an `S2` as arguments to support that.

Comment: @user8145466 `static_cast<S1&>(C) = someS1;` would do that. Without the reference, you would be making a temporary `S1` from `C` and trying to assign to it.

Comment: C is absolutely and necessarily S1 and S2 at once, I apologize if my comments made that unclear.

It's not an S1 od S2 in the logical sense, because I'm using it as a substitute for composition, but it is in a class hierachy sense.

A stupid example would be if you had a Car with a Velocity and Weight (which are structs for some reason). Usually a Car object would simply have a Velocity and Weight objects, but in my case it would be simpler for me if class Car : public Velocity, public Weight.

Bear in mind that this is just an example and my use case is somewhat more complex.

Comment: Perfect, François, that solves my conundrum exactly. I wasn't entirely sure if using a cast like that would have unintended consequences.

Actually both of your last comments are very helpful and I'll likely try out both. Feel free to create an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, it would be great if I could have some incompletely built `C` and then just do `c = s1; c = s2;` and only the `s1` and `s2` parts of `c` would change with each assignment.

What do you know! You can very easily achieve this exact syntax. Truth is, every base class has an `operator =` that you inherit. It is simply hidden by the derived class's own `operator =` (be it implicitly-generated or not). Thus, you only have to bring all of them back into scope:

```
class C : public I, public S1, public S2
{
public:
    using I::operator=;
    using S1::operator=;
    using S2::operator=;
};
```

... which then behaves exactly as you described. It is woth nothing, though, that the base classes are default-constructed, which might stretch what you mean by "incompletely built". It is unfortunately(?) impossible to have a valid derived object whose base classes have not been initialized at all.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87dc3c0ff1b8512e)

Comment: "*Truth is, every base class has an `operator =`*" not if it's implicitly deleted. If there is no copy constructor it might be the case. And if there is `operator=` it would be unreasonable not to have a copy c'tor as per 0-rule. Importing those operators does help if one wants to make a way for phased-partial initialization, which seems to be the real point. But the object is not really incompletely built. The parts are default or otherwise initialized.

Comment: @luk32 a deleted function is still a function, which participates in overload resolution and all.

Comment: My point is that OP states they have a problem with providing copy c'tor. This should translate to the `operator=`. They either do provide it, even if they don't know it, or they most probably need a custom explicit implementation of those operators for `C`. That's all. Taht said, I think your answer is still very useful as it seems that OP was not aware of the fact, that it's possible to have a separate overload for `operator=` for each of it compound types. So the desired syntax is very possible. The implementation would probably differ.

Comment: I haven't said I have a problem providing the copy ctor. I just said the same thing you said, that while it would work for me in this case, it's not a general solution and I'd like the general solution.

I also said that making a constructor is additionally complicated in my case because of the framework I'm using. Basically, it forces a RA then init model by design, which means that for every constructor I also need to write an additional static create function.

It's not any major complication by any means, but that's already 2 additional functions just for this simple thing.

Comment: But Quentin's solution (similar to Francois' with manually creating operator=s) also works fine for my needs, I just wasn't sure if that would do what I expected. It seems intuitive to me, but it also felt kind of wrong for some reason and I expected people here would point out  all sorts of memory leaks and object slicing that would happen if I were to do it like that.

Pleasantly surprised it's well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Composition via inheritance is a thing in languages that support it, but it is considered sub-par practice or even an anti-pattern vs composition in OOP.

With inheritance you get automatic method implementation and conversions. But you give up control over API. And you introduce coupling between `S1` and `S2`, because their implementation restrict each other, they can't have their members named the same, without introducing disambiguation. IMHO, there are more pitfalls due to more implicitness going with this way.

With composition you retain flexibility and fine grain control at the cost of explicit indirection... and the implementation effort which goes with it. Basically both API has to be copied if that the need, and it seems so in your case.

In other aspects they are pretty much the same, you can write code which would have the same usability client-wise. E.g. conversions and assignments.

You do or don't need copy c'tors in either way. For inheritance you can provide a `make_C` facility and forward c'tor arguments. `S1` and `S2` must provide any way of construction that you can reuse, that is true for both approach. You should be able to write appropriate c'tors for inheritance pattern.

If you need to decouple `C` from it's constituents, you need to somehow make copies in composition via membership as well.

You can't make `C` a facade around a reference using inheritance, as you could with membership composition by using a reference to the components. But if you need to share identity between an instance of `C` and it's respective parts, then it's not a real composition relation.

To say in general which will be less headache is pretty impossible, it's a design decision. More general and flexible is membership-wise composition, simpler probably inheritance. But I am not sure if I would trade it off.

I'd say that the more closed and ossified the design is, and you are sure no interference inheritance is safer to use for its pros. Otherwise, it might be a PIA and needing refactoring at some point of time. If you have huge classes repeating interfaces is going to be PIA.

Comment: I'm well aware of the issues and that's why I explicitly mentioned S1 and S2 were two completely unrelated POD structs. In fact their data was originally in C itself, but I decided to decouple it for various reasons.

As such, they are intrinsically tied to C. The only reason they're separate is to syntactically facilitate and simplify writing and reading Cs to and from the disk.

So the point is, there's basically no downside with inheritance in this particular case. The only thing pure composition buys me is having to access a proxy object every single time I need some data in C.

Comment: I know you are aware, and have constraints strengthening the case for multiple inheritance. I've tried to lay out some pros and cons in general case. I believe I've debunked, one or two assumptions. The design decision is yours. If you have to copy paste whole APIs, and you are sure objects are closed you seem to be capable of making an informed decision. I'd say copying the data whenever you need only a sub-component is a downside. Or you will have to extract an interface and use it anyways.

Comment: Well the implementation with composition already exists and works fine. I just got annoyed with how it clutters my code and decided to expirement with a MI version and see how I like that. But I got stuck at this part. Anyway, it&amp;#39;s a personal  program and I don&amp;#39;t have any deadlines or anything , so while I do appreciate your theoretical insights, I&amp;#39;d rather just do it and see for myself how I like it compared to what I had before. And if it explodes, it explodes.

Comment: But yeah I definitely understand the value of a general pro/con answer. Especially since I couldn&#39;t find a similar question anywhere (though it may exist). Perhaps adding some general code examples to your answer would assist in that goal.

Comment: How does it clutter your code? Except for having to explicitly write indirections it should be similar, with methods for getters and setter instead of members. Client-wise it should be similar. "*S1 and S2 were two completely unrelated*" and "*The only reason they're separate is to syntactically facilitate and simplify writing and reading Cs*" seem self-contradicting. If they are completely unrelated then that's the only reason needed to separate them. Btw have you considered reversing the approach and having `C` + two lightweight facade interfaces for whatever you need?

Comment: That's actually the only way it clutters my code, but since I have to use the indirection a lot in loops it proved especially annoying. To make everything less mysterious, I have a PlayingField class which has a h, w and a vector of blocks. On top of that it has bools that can vary from game to game, but are constant in a single PlayingField. 

So I took out h, w and the vector into one struct and the bools into another. Those are the only two things I require to load and save a PlayingField (which also has a whole bunch of other stuff) so I just dump them to the disk (being PODs and all).

Comment: The bools don't have anything to do with the h/w, nor the block vector.

However they all are unique and quintessential to PlayingField. It used to be that PlayingField just had those variables naked, but then I had to manually cherry pick the ones that were needed for a save game. 

So I made them into structs and used them as components. If I change them, I don't have to change the save/load code.

However, basically all the field functions use some variations on 2 loops that depend on h and w, so I'd like accessing h and w to be as terse as possible from the PlayingField class itself.